# Audit url open for permitted schemes. Allowing use of "file:" or custom schemes is often unexpected

Tags: python, pytest, codacy

I am using this statement in Python:

```
 jsonreq = json.dumps({'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'id': 'qwer', 'method': 'aria2.pauseAll'})
 jsonreq = jsonreq.encode('ascii')
 c = urllib.request.urlopen('http://localhost:6800/jsonrpc', jsonreq)
```

I am getting this warning/error when I perform code quality test

> Audit url open for permitted schemes. Allowing use of "file:" or custom schemes is often unexpected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is what you need

```
import urllib.request

req = urllib.request.Request('http://www.example.com')
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
    the_page = response.read()
```

Comment: Thanks Lamrin, it's working cool with test cases. So the file type read is this?

Answer (score 25):

Because I stumbled upon this question and the accepted answer did not work for me, I researched this myself:

#### Why urlib is a security risk

urlib not only opens http:// or https:// URLs, but also ftp:// and file://.
With this it might be possible to open local files on the executing machine which might be a security risk if the URL to open can be manipulated by an external user.

#### How to fix this

You are yourself responsible to validate the URL before opening it with urllib.
E.g.

```
if url.lower().startswith('http'):
  req = urllib.request.Request(url)
else:
  raise ValueError from None

with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as resp:
  [...]
```

#### How to fix this so the linter (e.g. [bandit](https://docs.openstack.org/bandit/latest/blacklists/blacklist_calls.html#b310-urllib-urlopen)) does no longer complain

At least bandit has a simple blacklist for the function call. As long as you use urllib, the linter will raise a warning. Even if you DO validate your input like shown above. (Or even use hardcoded URLs).

Add a `#nosec` comment to the line to suppress the warning from bandit or look up the suppression keyword for your linter/code-checker. It's best practice to also add additional comments stating WHY you think this is not worth a warning in your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. There are two typos in your code: 'urlib.request.Request' (Caps inverted) and ':' just after 'else'.

Answer (score 4):

For the people who couldn't solve it by above answers.
You could use `requests` library instead, which is not black listed in bandit.

https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blacklists/blacklist_calls.html#b310-urllib-urlopen

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.example.com'
the_page = requests.get(url)

print(the_page.json()) # if the response is json
print(the_page.text) # if the response is some text
```